# Generate Random Boolean Probability

Tags: c#, .net, random, boolean, probability

I only know how I can generate a random boolean value (true/false).
The default probability is 50:50

But how can I generate a true false value with my own probability?
Let's say it returns true with a probability of 40:60 or 20:80 etc...

Comment: Generate a random number between 1 and 100 and compare it to your distribution?

Comment: What you did so far?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

One way is checking that the return value of `Random.Next(100)` is less than your desired probability. I can't speak to the true 'randomness' of this method though.

Proper example, using desired probability of 20%:

```cs
Random gen = new Random();
int prob = gen.Next(100);
return prob < 20;
```

Comment: I would dare to assume that the predictability of these boolean values is just as random as `Random.Next()` would be. I don't know if that is the same as it's `randomness` though.

Comment: For me, in ASP.Net the working syntax turned out a little more elaborate:
`myRandomBool = new Random().Next(100) <= 50 ? true : false`

Comment: @E. Moffat: `? true : false` is redundant code.

Answer (score 22):

You generate a random number up to 100 exclusive and see if it's less than a given percent. Example:

```
if(random.Next(100) < 40) {
  // will be true 40% of the time
}
```

More generally, for a probability of X/Y, use an idiom like:

```
if(random.Next(Y) < X)
```

Answer (score 19):

Here is an extension method that will provide a random bool with specified probability (in percentage) of being true;

```
public static bool NextBool(this Random r, int truePercentage = 50)
{
    return r.NextDouble() < truePercentage / 100.0;
}
```

you can use this like

```
Random r = new Random();
r.NextBool(); // returns true or false with equal probability
r.NextBool(20); // 20% chance to be true;
r.NextBool(100); // always return true
r.NextBool(0); // always return false
```

Answer (score 8):

Assuming your probability is represented as `double` between 0.0 and 1.0, I would implement it more simply like this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
...
double trueProbability = 0.2;
bool result = rand.NextDouble() < trueProbability;
```

`result` will be `true` with the probability given by `trueProbability`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.nextdouble(v=vs.110).aspx

If this isn't "*random enough*", you can take a look at `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: to be fully representative of the trueProbability shouldn't you do a <= instead of < test?

Comment: @hubsonbropa No, since NextDouble() returns a value between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive). If you extrapolate to 100% probability, < 1 is sufficient.

Comment: @hubsonbropa Also, 0% should never be true. The only way to cover that case is to check for < 0.

Answer (score 7):

I think it can help you

```
Random gen = new Random();
bool result = gen.Next(100) < 50 ? true : false;
```

Comment: The expression `gen.Next(100) < 50` is boolean expression. No need to use the conditional operator here.

Answer (score 2):

For future knowledge:

40:60 would be:

```
var random = new Random();
return random.Next(10) < 4;
```

20:80 would be:

```
var random = new Random();
return random.Next(5) == 0
```

and 1:1 would be:

```
var random = new Random();
return random.Next(2) == 1;
```

Note: Just shorten the probability to the shortest variant - as for example: "random.Next(5) == 0" is quicker then "random.Next(100) <= 20
Though - if the probability changes from the user input - then it would look like:

```
[ModifierByChoice] bool GetProbability(int trueProbability, int falseProbability)
{
var random = new Random();
return random.Next(trueProbability, trueProbability + falseProbability) < trueProbability;
}
```

Comment: By reducing the fractions, the numbers written in the code suddenly become magical numbers. Unless you can and actually do prove that there is a significant slowdown by using larger numbers, the advice of reducing the fractions is counterproductive. Furthermore it may confuse beginning programmers that you sometimes use the `<` operator and sometimes the `==`, once even comparing to zero and the other time comparing to nonzero.

Answer (score -3):

```
Random gen = new Random();
var boolVal = gen.Next(0, 1)==1? true : false;
```

Comment: The question was: `But how can I generate a true false value with my own probability? Let's say it returns true with a probability of 40:60 or 20:80 etc...`. This answer is wrong.